# Laravel 5: Save extra cached data

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Is there a way to Store extra informations related to cached data?

Laravel 5 default:

```
Cache::add('key', 'value', $minutes);
```

I need to store `user_id` too, to determine this cache related to which user,

and will add `user_id` to `cache` table design,

thx

Answer (score 1):

You should make it with the `key` attribute:

```
Cache::add('key_from_user_' . $user_id, 'value', $minutes);
```

Comment: So there is no way to handle it separately?

Comment: I don't think so, a Cache is a simple key/value system

Comment: You should be able to store it as an array and it would have the same effect.

Comment: If you store the value as an array with the user id, the key would be the same for all users. So the information of only one user could be saved at a time... Am I wrong?

Comment: Sometimes system require clear custom user cache, and it will be easier if I able to "select" & "delete" custom user cache

Comment: Then, to remove a specific user cache: `Cache::forget('key_from_user_' . $user_id);` ?

Comment: If this solution can't feed your needs, you should take a look at the tags functionnality: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/cache#cache-tags However, as the doc says, this is not compatible with filesystem and database cache drivers

Comment: Yeah that's okay to have one key for all users because it returns an array.  Don't make it harder than it needs to be...  `$allUserData = cache('userInfo');  $userData = $allUserData[$userId];`

Comment: Ho yes ok, I see what you mean, this should also work! But if you have a lot of users, that would mean that `$allUserData` contain all of users information, stored in the server memory at every call